# Query_String / Query_String_Decoded don't hold Post Parameters

Tags: httprequest, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have an Agent which should accept Post parameters, sent from An App in Titanium,

In the App i send a httprequest, e.g:

```
var params = {
"Param1":"Test",
"Param2":"Sth"
}
var http = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient()
  http.open("POST","server/db.nsf/agent?OpenAgent",true);
  http.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + Ti.Utils.base64encode(username + ':' + password));

  http.send(params)
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
      var response = http.responseData
          callback(response)
    }
```

And in the Agent i have the following Code:

```
Dim session As NotesSession
Dim doc As NotesDocument

Set doc = session.DocumentContext

Print (doc.Query_String(0))
Print (doc.Query_String_Decoded(0))
```

I also added 2 hidden, computed forms `Query_String` and `Query_String_Decoded` with its name as value
Just to make sure.

And tried `@UrlQueryString``

But the responseData is only the 
`OpenAgent`
parameter from the Url

Could anyone help me to find the right way to get the Post Data, sent from the httprequest

Thanks for your help in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Request_Content CGI variable and not Query_string.

---

You could also use XPages and create an XAgent instead. Values posted to XPages can be read using param.get(). I have written a blog post about a [HTTP request consumer in XPages](http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2010/12/http-request-consumer-in-xpages.html) that you can use as inspiration.

Comment: Thank you very much =) 
That was exactly what i needed, saved me a lot of frustration

I'll definetly give the post a look, as i just wanted to try using an xpage because i struggled with the Query_String/Request_Content variable.

But i never did anything with xpages, so this may be a good start to begin with